# qt sqlite insert into autoincrement table yields two rows

Tags: qt, sqlite, auto-increment, insertion

Hi
I have a sqlite db which I am manipulating using qts built in sqlite database driver.

I have a small test app that allows me to run an sql query from a line edit and it will be executed and the results are then updated in a view of the relevant model.

I have created a table which uses autoincremented primary key values, but if I execute an insert statement without providing the key, I get two rows inserted, each with an autoincremented value.

If I provide the key value, only one row is created. Any ideas why this is?

Table is simple enough, e.g

```
CREATE TABLE GroupNames (  ID    integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,  Name  varchar(50))
```

and when I run the query

```
insert into groupnames (name) values ("testName");
```

I get two new rows with autoincremented ids. However, if I run

```
insert into groupnames (id, name) values (100, "testName");
```

I get one row as expected, with the correct id 100.
Also of note is that if I try

```
insert into table groupnames (id, name) values (100, "testName");
insert into table groupnames (name) values ("testName");
```

the query does not run.
The qt code to run the query could not be simpler:

```
QSqlQuery *DbCore::run_query(const QString &query_string)
{
  QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database(defConnectionName);    
  if(!db.isOpen())
    return NULL;
  QSqlQuery *q = new QSqlQuery(query_string, db);  
  q->exec();    
  return q;
}
```

I have added some logging code to check that the query is executed once:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database(defConnectionName);    
  if(!db.isOpen())
    return NULL;

  qDebug() << "Running query:" << query_string;
  QSqlQuery *q = new QSqlQuery(query_string, db);  
  if(!q->exec())
    qDebug() << "Error running query:" << q->lastError();    
  return q;
```

The log confirms that I'm only executing once:

```
Running query: "insert into groupnames (name) values ("hello")"
```

If i then check the database using sqlite3 shell (to remove any doubt about qt views etc):

```
sqlite> select * from groupnames;
1|hello
2|hello
```

Comment: Are you certain your `run_query` is not being called twice? Add some logging before and after `q->exec()` and _log the return code_. Update your post with the logging information please.

Comment: As i see in the documentation, when you create a QSqlQuery the way you do, the query, if not empty, is executed. 
To create the QSqlQuery and execute the query, use this: `QSqlQuery *q = new QSqlQuery(db);
q->exec(query_string)` 
To see the last executed query, use `QSqlQuery::lastQuery()`
And for the last query that was **successfully** executed `QSqlQuery::executedQuery()` Hope this helps.

Comment: that's it! thankyou! i was only getting one row when i provided the index, because the second query failed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question was answered above in a comment:
As i see in the documentation, when you create a QSqlQuery the way you do, the query, if not empty, is executed. To create the QSqlQuery and execute the query, use this: QSqlQuery *q = new QSqlQuery(db); q->exec(query_string) To see the last executed query, use QSqlQuery::lastQuery() And for the last query that was successfully executed QSqlQuery::executedQuery() Hope this helps. – Hector Mar 16 at